# Elastic Search cancel long running task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

For Elastic Search version 6.0

to cancel a running task:

```
POST _tasks/node_id:task_id/_cancel
```

I am following the same statement, but in actual it is unable to cancel the task. After running this command if I run get command to fetch all running task, the particular task don't get cancel.

If I hit cancel statement again, it gives statement that `task_id` is already cancelled but in reality it doesn't get cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the `_tasks/<id>/_cancel` endpoint only signifies to ES that the task **should** be cancelled. ES will then cancel the task **as soon as it possibly can**.

It might not be immediate, though, for instance, if you have a very complex search that takes a long time (e.g. wildcard queries with leading wildcards).

If you check the [`ContextIndexSearcher`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/internal/ContextIndexSearcher.java) class and look for all places where `checkCancelled.run()` is called, those are the only phases when a query can be cancelled, but sometimes a phase can take a long time before being eligible for cancellation.

If your task is a search task, then you might try to leverage the [`timeout` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-your-data.html#search-timeout) to see if it helps (it might not always for the same reasons as mentioned above).

Comment: I am using ES version 6.0, and the timeout parameter is not supported in that.
I am having some very large search queries that run for long period of time, I want to kill those running tasks, but ES is not killing, they get executed even after I run cancel command.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, for the reasons I mentioned. And probably in ES 6, `ContextIndexSearcher` probably wasn't at the level it is now. Do you want to share your query in another question, because that's the only leverage you have.

Comment: to get the running tasks I run the command:
1. GET _tasks?actions=*search  (I only want to fetch search related tasks)

So from this I get the node_id:task_id
To cancel the running task:
1.POST _tasks/node_id:task_id/_cancel

ES documentation also show these statements but they arent working.
Link to doc:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/tasks.html

Comment: I meant your search queries, the ones that are taking long to run, this is the axis we should focus on and make them faster. Query cancellation is merely a help but not the solution here.

Comment: Oh!!, That I cant optimize. These are some corner cases I need to handle. For some search query gets too long so I need to kill them.

Comment: There are always possible ways to improve search queries and make them faster, but I can't tell you if I don't know how it's looking.

Comment: No, I am finding a way to kill the query but no luck as of now. Optimizing query is the next step but as of now I am focusing on how to kill the ongoing task.

Comment: I'm afraid you won't be able to (especially in 6.0 since it's a very old version), we should focus on improving your query, I'm sure there's more chance there :-)

Comment: I have started doing R&D on the upgraded version. Planning to shift ES to latest version. Will mention the issues if I face any.

Comment: Ok let us know how it goes

Comment: yes, we upgraded our ES from 6.0 to 7, giving us options to use timeout parameter. it solves the issue.
Thanks for the help on the issue.